# Show that $\partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu} = - j_\nu F^{\mu\nu}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In a theoretical physics homework problem, I have to show the following:
$$\partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu} = - j_\nu F^{\mu\nu}$$

Where $T$ is the Energy-Momentum-Tensor, $j$ the generalized current and $F$ the Field-Tensor. We use the $g$ for the metric tensor, I think in English the $\eta$ is more common.

I know the following relationships:

- Current and magnetic potential with Lorenz gauge condition:
  $$\mathop\Box A^\mu = \mu_0 j^\mu$$
- Energy-Momentum-Tensor:
  $$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac1{\mu_0} g^{\mu\alpha} F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\beta\nu} + \frac1{4\mu_0} g^{\mu\nu} F_{\kappa\lambda} F^{\kappa\lambda}$$
- Field-Tensor:
  $$F^{\mu\nu} = 2 \partial^{[\mu} A^{\nu]} = \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu} A^{\mu}$$
- d'Alembert operator:
  $$\mathop\Box = \partial_\mu \partial^\mu$$
- Bianchi identity:
  $$\partial^{[\mu} F^{\nu\alpha]} = 0$$

So far I have set all the definitions into the formula I have to show, but I only end up a lot of terms from antisymmetrisation and product rule. I also drew all what I have in [Penrose graphical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation), but I still cannot see how to tackle this problem.

Could somebody please give me a hint into the right direction?

Comment: Look at $F_{\alpha \beta}$ in $T_{\mu\nu}$ I think that $\beta$ is not right because the free indices are $\mu \nu$ and you have an extra free index $\beta$

Comment: The first term in the expression for $T^{\mu\nu}$ should be something like $F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\nu}_{\alpha}$

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it. I just typed it wrong here, that was not source of my confusion so far.

Comment: What terms are automatically zero thanks to antisymmetrization?  Which ones can you eliminate thanks to the EOM of $A_{\mu}$?

Comment: I think you're missing the most important equation of all:  that $\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = \mu_0 j^\nu$.

Comment: @twistor59: that's what he has, he's just lowered the first index with the metric.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: There was a $F$ missing before.

Comment: @queueoverflow By the way, in English $g$ is used for any general metric, while $\eta$ is reserved for the Minkowski metric.

Comment: @twistor59 So it should be the first index on the top and second index on the bottom? Like $F^{\mu\alpha}F^\nu_{\ \ \ \alpha}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at different terms from differentiating $T^{\mu\nu} $.

The first from differentiating $ g^{\mu\alpha} F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\beta\nu}$ is
$$\partial_\nu g^{\mu\alpha} F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\beta\nu}=
 g^{\mu\alpha} F_{\alpha\beta} (\partial_\nu F^{\beta\nu})
 +(\partial^\nu F^{\mu\beta}) F_{\beta\nu}=
 - \mu_0 F_{\alpha\beta} j^\beta
 +(\partial^\nu F^{\mu\beta}) F_{\beta\nu}$$

The first term is exactly what you want, the second cancels against the stuff you get from differentiating $g^{\mu\nu} F_{\kappa\lambda} F^{\kappa\lambda}$:

$$\partial^\mu F_{\kappa\lambda} F^{\kappa\lambda}=2 F_{\kappa\lambda} (\partial^\mu F^{\kappa\lambda})=-2 F_{\kappa\lambda} (\partial^\kappa F^{\lambda\mu}+\partial^\lambda F^{\mu\kappa})
=-4 (\partial^\nu F^{\mu\beta}) F_{\beta\nu}$$
where in the second equality sign we have used Bianchi identity and in the last equality we 
have used
$$
F_{\kappa\lambda} \partial^\kappa F^{\lambda\mu}
\underset{\text{relabel indecies}}=
 F_{\nu\beta}\partial^\nu F^{\beta \mu}
\underset{\text{antisym. of $F$}}=
F_{\beta\nu}\partial^\nu F^{\mu\beta}
$$
This exactly cancels the second term in the first equation.

Comment: With Murphrid's comment in mind, I am able to follow your answer, except for the very last equality sign. I renamed the indices in my notes to match yours, but I do not see why $\partial^\beta F^{\nu\mu} = \partial^\nu F^{\mu\beta}$ holds.

Comment: It doesn't. You should split the two terms (including the $F_{\kappa \lambda}$) and relabel the dummy indices on the second term.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
        \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{EM}}
        &= \partial_\mu \left(F^{\mu\lambda} F^\nu_{\ \lambda}\right) - \frac{1}{4} \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \left(F^{\lambda\sigma} F_{\lambda\sigma}\right) \\
        &= F^{\mu\lambda} \partial_\mu F^\nu_{\ \lambda} + F^\nu_{\ \lambda} \partial_\mu F^{\mu\lambda} - \frac{1}{4} \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \left(F^{\lambda\sigma} F_{\lambda\sigma}\right) \\
        &= F^{\mu\lambda} \partial_\mu F^\nu_{\ \lambda} + F^\nu_{\ \lambda} \partial_\mu F^{\mu\lambda} - \frac{1}{4} \partial^\nu \left(F^{\lambda\sigma} F_{\lambda\sigma}\right)
\end{align*}

From Maxwell's Equations:

$$
        \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = -J^\nu
$$
We have:
$$
    \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{EM}} = -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + F^{\mu\lambda} \partial_\mu F^\nu_{\ \lambda} - \frac{1}{4} \partial^\nu \left(F^{\lambda\sigma} F_{\lambda\sigma}\right)
$$
Also we have:
\begin{align*}
    \partial^\nu \left(F^{\lambda\sigma} F_{\lambda\sigma}\right)
    &= F^{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F_{\lambda\sigma} + F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma} \\
    &= \eta^{\lambda\tau} \eta^{\rho\sigma} F_{\tau\rho} \partial^\nu F_{\lambda\sigma} + F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma} \\
    &= F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu \left(\eta^{\lambda\tau} \eta^{\rho\sigma} F_{\tau\rho}\right) + F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma} \\
    &= F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma} + F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma} \\
    &= 2F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma}
\end{align*}
and the same:
\begin{align}
        F^{\mu\lambda} \partial_\mu F^\nu_{\ \lambda}
        &= \left(\eta^{\mu\alpha} \eta^{\beta\lambda} F_{\alpha \beta}\right) \left(\eta_{\mu\gamma} \partial^{\gamma}\right) \left(\eta_{\sigma\lambda} F^{\nu\sigma}\right) \\
        &= \eta^{\mu\alpha} \eta^{\beta\lambda} \eta_{\mu\gamma} \eta_{\sigma\lambda} \left(F_{\alpha \beta} \partial^{\gamma} F^{\nu\sigma}\right) \\
        &= \delta^\alpha_\gamma \delta^\beta_\sigma \left(F_{\alpha \beta} \partial^{\gamma} F^{\nu\sigma}\right) \\
        &= F_{\gamma\sigma} \partial^{\gamma} F^{\nu\sigma} \\
        &= F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda}
    \end{align}
so that:
\begin{align}
        \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{EM}}
        &= -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} - \frac{1}{2} F_{\lambda\sigma} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\sigma} \\
        &= -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} - \frac{1}{2} F_{\lambda\mu} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\mu} \\
        &= -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} + \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} - \frac{1}{2} F_{\lambda\mu} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\mu} \\
        &= -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + \frac{1}{2} \left(F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} + F_{\lambda\mu} \partial^\lambda F^{\nu\mu} - F_{\lambda\mu} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\mu}\right) \\
        &= -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + \frac{1}{2} \left(F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} + F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\lambda F^{\mu\nu} + F_{\mu\lambda} \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\mu}\right) \\
        &= -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda + \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\lambda} \left(\partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} + \partial^\lambda F^{\mu\nu} + \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\mu}\right)
    \end{align}
Lastly we use Bianchi Identities:
$$
    \partial^\mu F^{\nu\lambda} + \partial^\lambda F^{\mu\nu} + \partial^\nu F^{\lambda\mu} = 0
    \Leftrightarrow
    \partial^{[\mu} F^{\nu\lambda]} = 0
$$
we get:
$$
    \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{EM}} = -F^\nu_{\ \lambda} J^\lambda
$$

---

**I don't know if we can change the $\lambda$ to $\mu$ in the last equation, maybe we can because it is a dummy index.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You can reuse the same dummy index on either side, but ti doesn't really matter because it is a dummy index anyway.