# Derivative of $T^{\mu \nu}_{\mathrm{mat}}$ in terms of $F^{\mu \nu}$ and $j^\nu$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

*A friend of mine encountered a problem while studying GR. I'm going to answer it myself if I get some time, but here it is.*

The (symmetrized) energy-momentum tensor for the electromagnetic field is $$T^{\mu \nu} = F^{\mu \lambda} F^{\nu}_{\,\, \lambda} - \frac{1}{4} \eta^{\mu \nu} F^{\lambda \sigma} F_{\lambda \sigma} \, .$$

In this calculation, she had to assume conservation of energy-momentum in the form $\partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu} = 0$ to figure how it works out in the presence of field sources. In other words:
$$T^{\mu \nu} = T^{\mu \nu}_\mathrm{matter} + T^{\mu \nu}_\mathrm{field}$$
The step that confused her was showing that
 $$ \partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu}_\mathrm{matter} = F^{\nu}_{\, \, \mu} j^{\mu} $$

I tried to write it out using the Maxwell field equation $$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = j^\nu$$ and the Bianchi identity $$\partial_{[ \lambda} F_{\mu \nu ]} = 0$$ but something smelled fishy in my calculations and I didn't manage to get back to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51778/2451

Comment: Yes, it's an exact duplicate, thanks! My mistake, feel free to close it. Or should I remove it?